# Scrapy with multiple pages

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I have created a simple scrapy project, In which, I got the total page number from the initial site example.com/full. Now I need to scrape all the page starting from example.com/page-2 to 100(if total page count is 100). How can I do that?

Any advice would be helpful.

Code:

```
import scrapy


class AllSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'all'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['https://example.com/full/']
    total_pages = 0

def parse(self, response):
    total_pages = response.xpath("//body/section/div/section/div/div/ul/li[6]/a/text()").extract_first()
    #urls = ('https://example.com/page-{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,total_pages))
    print(total_pages)
```

Update #1:

I tried using that `urls = ('https://example.com/page-{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,total_pages))` but its not working, may be i'm doing something wrong.

Update #2:
I have changed my code like this one

```
class AllSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'all'
allowed_domains = ['sanet.st']
start_urls = ['https://sanet.st/full/']
total_pages = 0

def parse(self, response):
    total_pages = response.xpath("//body/section/div/section/div/div/ul/li[6]/a/text()").extract_first()
    for page in range(2, int(total_pages)):
        url = 'https://sanet.st/page-'+str(page)
        yield scrapy.Request(url)
        title =  response.xpath('//*[@class="list_item_title"]/h2/a/span/text()').extract()
        print(title)
```

But still the loop showing only the first page title repeatedly.
I need to extract the title from different pages and print it in the prompt.
How can i do that?

Comment: Considering that you can either select or generate all pages URL, you must create a loop and `yield scrapy_request` for each one of them, and set the `callback` parameter with the name of the method that will parse each page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must search for the 'next_page' object and continue to loop while it is on the page.

[image: img with next_page element]

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request


class SanetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sanet'
    allowed_domains = ['sanet.st']
    start_urls = ['https://sanet.st/full/']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            # Do something.
            'result': response.xpath('//h3[@class="posts-results"]/text()').extract_first()
        }

        # next_page = /page-{}/ where {} number of page.
        next_page = response.xpath('//a[@data-tip="Next page"]/@href').extract_first()

        # next_page = https://sanet.st/page-{}/ where {} number of page.
        next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)

        # If next_page have value
        if next_page:
            # Recall parse with url https://sanet.st/page-{}/ where {} number of page.
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

If you run this code with the "-o sanet.json" key you will get the following result.

> scrapy runspider sanet.py -o sanet.json

```
[
{"result": "results 1 - 15 from 651"},
{"result": "results 16 - 30 from 651"},
{"result": "results 31 - 45 from 651"},
...
etc.
...
{"result": "results 631 - 645 from 651"},
{"result": "results 646 - 651 from 651"}
]
```

Comment: and what if there is no next-page object? just page numbers?

Answer (score 1):

```
from scrapy.http import Request


def parse(self, response):
    total_pages = response.xpath("//body/section/div/section/div/div/ul/li[6]/a/text()").extract_first()
    urls = ('https://example.com/page-{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,total_pages))
    for url in urls:
        yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_page)

def parse_page(self, response):
    # do the stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

an alternative way as shown in the [tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#a-shortcut-for-creating-requests) is to use `yield response.follow(url, callback=self.parse_page)` and it supports relative URLs directly.